# Jersey converting from ClientResponse to Response

Tags: java, jersey

I'm currently using Jersey as a proxy REST api to call another RESTful web service. Some of the calls will be passed to and from with minimal processing in my server.

Is there a way to do this cleanly? I was thinking of using the Jersey Client to make the REST call, then converting the ClientResponse into a Response. Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

Some example code:

```
@GET
@Path("/groups/{ownerID}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String getDomainGroups(@PathParam("ownerID") String ownerID) {
    WebResource r = client.resource(URL_BASE + "/" + URL_GET_GROUPS + "/" + ownerID);
    String resp = r.get(String.class);
    return resp;
}
```

This works if the response is always a success, but if there's a 404 on the other server, I'd have to check the response code. In other words, is there clean way to just return the response I got?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no convenience method as far as I am aware. You can do this:

```
public Response getDomainGroups(@PathParam("ownerID") String ownerID) {
    WebResource r = client.resource(URL_BASE + "/" + URL_GET_GROUPS + "/" + ownerID);
    ClientResponse resp = r.get(ClientResponse.class);
    return clientResponseToResponse(resp);
}

public static Response clientResponseToResponse(ClientResponse r) {
    // copy the status code
    ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(r.getStatus());
    // copy all the headers
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : r.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
        for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
            rb.header(entry.getKey(), value);
        }
    }
    // copy the entity
    rb.entity(r.getEntityInputStream());
    // return the response
    return rb.build();
}
```

Comment: That works well for me, however, if I try to log errors it seems to alter the response.  For example
if(r.getStatus() != 200){
   logger.error(IOUtils.toString(loggingResponse.getEntityInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
}
Now it logs the error, but no longer returns the response to the originally caller.

Answer (score 2):

for me answer from Martin throw:
*JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream* 
Change from

```
rb.entity(r.getEntityInputStream());
```

to

```
rb.entity(r.getEntity(new GenericType<String>(){}));
```

helped.